Data loss protection alert message
We are creating a web app in SAPUI5 framework. Is there a way how to change the text in the alert popup that is displayed when navigating from the page, when the dirtyFlag is set to true? Now there is a different message when pressing back buttons and different message when pressing bookmark in the bookmark bar. We want to unify the message. Any suggestions?
